# How to stop Google+ Notifications?

Tags: google-plus, notifications

Google+ unread notifications serve their purpose well on Google+ website but I don't understand their need of popping up across entire Google ecosystem. For ex: If I am doing some search on Google, I am not really interested in seeing G+ notifications. Similarly on Google drive etc.
Any idea how can I stop (or turn off) Google plus notifications?

[image: how to stop google plus unread notification]

Comment: Which notifications do you mean? The only notifications you can control from your settings are the ones that go to your email and/or phone.

Comment: @AlE.I was referring to G+ unread notifications. I've added the image now to make question more clear. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Ah, in the Google bar. There is no way to turn that off within any Google settings.

Comment: yeah, there is no google setting for this but there might be some browser plugin/extension etc that might help in this case?

Comment: If simply _hiding_ this image works for you then yes, a browser plugin will help.

Answer (score -1):

You can turn off by following the below steps:

1. Click on Google+ and then select home -> settings
2. There is an option called Receive notifications, where you have to unchecked the icon for the various option under that like post, circles.
3. Once it is done, now new post or any friends added to the circles won't be notified in the bell.

Comment: the option you suggested is for email or phone notifications not for desktop browsers.

Comment: This settings worked for me in desktop browser also.

Comment: The line exactly below "Receive Notifications" says "Get notified by email or phone when someone..." so it should only be for **email** and **phone**.